# Не сохраняется массивы в UserDefaults в SpriteKit

Tags: swift3, spritekit

Работаю над spritekit swift. У меня есть singleton Model.

```
class Model {
static let sharedInstance = Model() // Singleton   
//Variables
var levelPassed = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
var levelCompleted1 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
var levelCompleted2 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
}
```

И в GameScene есть функция, которая срабатывает при завершении уровня

```
    func completeLevel(){
    if levelPassed[gSceneDifficulty.rawValue] == 0 {
        Model.sharedInstance.levelPassed[gSceneDifficulty.rawValue] = 1
        UserDefaults.standard.set(Model.sharedInstance.levelPassed, forKey: "levelPassed")
    }
    if levelCompleted1[gSceneDifficulty.rawValue] == 0 {
        if complete == 1 {            Model.sharedInstance.levelCompleted1[gSceneDifficulty.rawValue] = 1
            UserDefaults.standard.set(levelCompleted1, forKey: "levelCompleted1")
        }
    }
    if levelCompleted2[gSceneDifficulty.rawValue] == 0 {
        if complete == 2 {
        Model.sharedInstance.levelCompleted[gSceneDifficulty.rawValue] = 2
           UserDefaults.standard.set(levelCompleted2, forKey: "levelCompleted2")
        }
    }
}
```

Мне нужно заполнить массивы единицами для пользователя, таким образом я смогу сохранять данные. Ошибки не вылазит, он просто не сохраняет получившийся массив. Как сохранять массивы?

Comment: Опишите более подробнее какая ошибка или что не получается?

Comment: Мне нужно заполнить массивы единицами для пользователя, таким образом я смогу сохранять данные.  Ошибки не вылазит, он просто не сохраняет получившийся массив. Как сохранять массивы?

Answer (score 0):

```
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```